# Checkout fields to have 2 columns in Woocommerce cart page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have found the solution to have the following fields in-line with each other on the woocommerce checkout page - orignal question here: [Customizing checkout fields on 2 columns in Woocommerce cart page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48793085/customizing-checkout-fields-on-2-columns-in-woocommerce-cart-page)

Most fields with this code become inline, however the following fields have no affect:

- Phone
- Email
- Address line 2

I think it's an error within the billing section in the code. This is the full code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_checkout_billing_fields', 20, 1 );
function custom_checkout_billing_fields( $fields ){

if( is_cart()){ // <== On cart page only
    // Change placeholder
    $fields['billing_phone']['placeholder']     = __( 'Phone', $domain );
    $fields['billing_email']['placeholder']     = __( 'Email', $domain );
    $fields['billing_address_2']['placeholder'] = __( 'Address line 2', $domain );

    // Change class
    $fields['billing_phone']['class']     = array('form-row-last'); //  50%
    $fields['billing_email']['class']     = array('form-row-first');  //  50%
    $fields['billing_address_2']['class'] = array('form-row-wide');  // 100%
}
return $fields;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'custom_default_address_fields', 20, 1);
function custom_default_address_fields( $address_fields ){

if( ! is_cart()){ // <== On cart page only
    // Change placeholder
    $address_fields['first_name']['placeholder'] = __( 'First name', $domain );
    $address_fields['last_name']['placeholder']  = __( 'Last name', $domain );
    $address_fields['address_1']['placeholder']  = __( 'Address line 1', $domain );
    $address_fields['state']['placeholder']      = __( 'County', $domain );
    $address_fields['postcode']['placeholder']   = __( 'Post Code', $domain );
    $address_fields['city']['placeholder']       = __( 'Town/City', $domain );

    // Change class
    $address_fields['first_name']['class'] = array('form-row-first'); //  50%
    $address_fields['last_name']['class']  = array('form-row-last');  //  50%
    $address_fields['address_1']['class']  = array('form-row-wide');  // 100%
    $address_fields['state']['class']      = array('form-row-last');  // 50%
    $address_fields['postcode']['class']   = array('form-row-first'); //  50%
    $address_fields['city']['class']       = array('form-row-first');  //  50%
}
return $address_fields;
}
```

Here is the css code:

```
.form-row-wide,
.form-row-first,
.form-row-last {
    clear: both !important;
    float: none !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    margin-right: 0 !important;
}

@media (min-width: 768px){
    .form-row-first {
       width: 47% !important;
       float: left !important;
       margin-right: 5.8% !important;
       clear: both !important;
    }
    .form-row-last {
       width: 47% !important;
       float: right !important;
       margin-right: 0 !important;
       clear: none !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean the checkout page or cart page?

Comment: checkout page @kashalo

Comment: alright i will rewrite the code for u

Comment: thank you @kashalo

Comment: did the code below did the job for you? if yes i will appreciated if you marked as resolved, if not let me know

Comment: @kashalo yes it worked - thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have some mistake in your code and i believe the answer which you took those code from  is for similar solution and not for your case.

So if you want to display the checkout filed inline you need only the following:

```
 add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_checkout_billing_fields', 20, 1);
 function custom_checkout_billing_fields($fields)
 {
$domain = 'woocommerce';
// Remove billing address 2
unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_2']);

// Change class
$fields['billing']['billing_phone']['class'] = array('form-row-first'); //  50%
$fields['billing']['billing_email']['class'] = array('form-row-last'); //  50%
$fields['billing']['billing_address_1']['class'] = array('form-row-first'); //  50%
$fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['class'] = array('form-row-last'); //  50%
$fields['billing']['billing_company']['class'] = array('form-row-wide'); // 100%

// Change placeholder this below is just if you wanto to change the place holder  you can remove theme if you don't want to change that
$fields['billing']['billing_phone']['placeholder'] = __('Telefon', $domain);
$fields['billing']['billing_email']['placeholder'] = __('Email', $domain);
$fields['billing']['billing_company']['placeholder'] = __('Firmanavn', $domain);

return $fields;
}
```

in above code only five filed which we have change the classes if you want the rest let me know or you can add them by yourself by looking for each filed name and change the class in the way you want

Remember there is block of code in this function that change the placeholder if you don't want them you can simple delete them