# Woocommerce checkout page changes not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I have tried several ways now to change the form field of billing and shipping. I am trying to do the following:

**in billing section**

- change address 2 placeholder content
- change address 2 label
- address 1 change class to 50%
- address 2 change class to 50%
- city change class to 50%
- state change class to 50%
- postcode change class to 50%
- phone change class to 50%
- address 2 remove reader class

**in shipping address section**

- address 2 change placeholder address 2 change label
- address 1 change class 50%
- address 2 change class 50%
- state change class to 50%
- postcode change class to 50%
- address 2 remove text reader class

They need a different layout so I can't use the "default" hook (which works). Here is my code so far.

```
//customize woocommerce checkout fields
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'jm_checkout_billing_fields', 20, 1 );
function jm_checkout_billing_fields( $billing_fields ){


       // Change placeholder
       $billing_fields['billing']['billing_address_2']['placeholder'] = __('Apt #, Floor, etc', $domain);

       // Change label
       $billing_fields['billing']['billing_address_2']['label'] = __('Apt #, Floor, etc', $domain);
       
       // Change class
       $billing_fields['billing']['billing_address_1']['class']   = array('form-row-first'); //  50%
       $billing_fields['billing']['billing_address_2']['class']   = array('form-row-last');  //  50%
       $billing_fields['billing']['billing_city']['class']   = array('form-row-first'); //  50%
       $billing_fields['billing']['billing_state']['class']   = array('form-row-last');  //  50%
       $billing_fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['class']   = array('form-row-first'); //  50%
       $billing_fields['billing']['billing_phone']['class']   = array('form-row-last');  //  50%
       $billing_fields['billing']['billing_address_2']['label_class'] = array(); // No label class

   return $billing_fields;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_address_fields', 'jm_address_fields', 20, 1);
function jm_address_fields( $address_fields ){
   
   if(  is_checkout()){ // On checkout page only
       // Change placeholder
       $address_fields['address_2']['placeholder'] = __( 'Apt #, Floor, etc', $domain );

       //change label
       $address_fields['address_2']['label'] = __( 'Apt #, Floor, etc', $domain );



       // Change class
       $address_fields['address_1']['class'] = array('form-row-first'); //  50%
       $address_fields['address_2']['class']  = array('form-row-last');  //  50%
       $address_fields['state']['class']  = array('form-row-first');  //  50%
       $address_fields['postcode']['class']  = array('form-row-last');  //  50%
       $address_fields['address_2']['label_class'] = array(); // No label class


   }
   return $address_fields;
}
```

If I use 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' for everything, it works, but again, I need billing address to be a different layout than my address fields.

I can have these be "defaults" but it needs to be different starting with "city"

- change address 2 placeholder content
- change address 2 label
- address 1 change class to 50%
- address 2 change class to 50%
- address 2 remove text reader class

I followed the answer here and have been making changes to try and get it to work separately: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48801880/14664702

Comment: You haven't mentioned in your code what you are trying to achieve. You have only mentioned what doesn't work, which again is of no use if we don't know what you are trying to do. Explain what exactly is the issue that you are trying to solve.

Comment: @bhanu I updated my post to include more details.  Thank you

Comment: What theme are you using @jmasked ? I can try this on storefront, because there can be a lot of custom CSS written making the answer invalid.

Comment: thank you @bhanu I am using hello-theme

Comment: Please share its link??

Comment: I was asking for the link of theme, if it is publically available. 
?

Answer (score 1):

The way you can change address field is by using `woocommerce_default_address_fields` filter. Use the following code to make the changes.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'bks_override_default_address_fields' );

// Our hooked in function - $address_fields is passed via the filter!
function bks_override_default_address_fields( $address_fields ) {
    $address_fields['address_1']['placeholder'] = 'Apt #, Floor, etc';
    $address_fields['address_2']['label'] = 'Apt #, Floor, etc';
    $address_fields['address_1']['class']   = array('form-row-first', 'address-field');
    $address_fields['address_2']['class']   = array('form-row-last', 'address-field');
    $address_fields['city']['class']   = array('form-row-first'); //  50%
    $address_fields['state']['class']   = array('form-row-last');  //  50%
    $address_fields['postcode']['class']   = array('form-row-first'); //  50%
    $address_fields['address_2']['label_class'] = array(); // No label class

    return $address_fields;
}
```

These are just few changes that I quickly picked up from your code. I haven't gone through your complete list of changes as I think you will be able to change those from the above code.

I am adding the default fields here. These are the actual default fields. These were picked up from here. https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/includes/class-wc-countries.php#L683-L755

```
$fields = array(
    'first_name' => array(
        'label'        => __( 'First name', 'woocommerce' ),
        'required'     => true,
        'class'        => array( 'form-row-first' ),
        'autocomplete' => 'given-name',
        'priority'     => 10,
    ),
    'last_name'  => array(
        'label'        => __( 'Last name', 'woocommerce' ),
        'required'     => true,
        'class'        => array( 'form-row-last' ),
        'autocomplete' => 'family-name',
        'priority'     => 20,
    ),
    'company'    => array(
        'label'        => __( 'Company name', 'woocommerce' ),
        'class'        => array( 'form-row-wide' ),
        'autocomplete' => 'organization',
        'priority'     => 30,
        'required'     => 'required' === get_option( 'woocommerce_checkout_company_field', 'optional' ),
    ),
    'country'    => array(
        'type'         => 'country',
        'label'        => __( 'Country / Region', 'woocommerce' ),
        'required'     => true,
        'class'        => array( 'form-row-wide', 'address-field', 'update_totals_on_change' ),
        'autocomplete' => 'country',
        'priority'     => 40,
    ),
    'address_1'  => array(
        'label'        => __( 'Street address', 'woocommerce' ),
        /* translators: use local order of street name and house number. */
        'placeholder'  => esc_attr__( 'House number and street name', 'woocommerce' ),
        'required'     => true,
        'class'        => array( 'form-row-wide', 'address-field' ),
        'autocomplete' => 'address-line1',
        'priority'     => 50,
    ),
    'address_2'  => array(
        'label'        => $address_2_label,
        'label_class'  => array( 'screen-reader-text' ),
        'placeholder'  => esc_attr( $address_2_placeholder ),
        'class'        => array( 'form-row-wide', 'address-field' ),
        'autocomplete' => 'address-line2',
        'priority'     => 60,
        'required'     => 'required' === get_option( 'woocommerce_checkout_address_2_field', 'optional' ),
    ),
    'city'       => array(
        'label'        => __( 'Town / City', 'woocommerce' ),
        'required'     => true,
        'class'        => array( 'form-row-wide', 'address-field' ),
        'autocomplete' => 'address-level2',
        'priority'     => 70,
    ),
    'state'      => array(
        'type'         => 'state',
        'label'        => __( 'State / County', 'woocommerce' ),
        'required'     => true,
        'class'        => array( 'form-row-wide', 'address-field' ),
        'validate'     => array( 'state' ),
        'autocomplete' => 'address-level1',
        'priority'     => 80,
    ),
    'postcode'   => array(
        'label'        => __( 'Postcode / ZIP', 'woocommerce' ),
        'required'     => true,
        'class'        => array( 'form-row-wide', 'address-field' ),
        'validate'     => array( 'postcode' ),
        'autocomplete' => 'postal-code',
        'priority'     => 90,
    ),
);
```

You can change any value from above array to get what you desire.

### Output

[image: checkout fields change]

Tested and **WORKS**.

> PS : Above array doesn't have phone field. You can use your orignal code for this particular field. `$billing_fields['billing']['billing_phone']['class']   = array('form-row-last');`. It should work just fine.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response.  I originally had used the exact format you suggested for the filter 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' however it was also changing the billing address defaults, regardless of me having specified address fields.  That's why I ran into the issue I have.  The billing address and shipping address need to have two different formats, starting at "city".  In billing city needs to have the class 'form-row-first' while in shipping it needs 'form-row-wide'.

Answer (score 0):

In specific cases, you need to use the "woocommerce_default_address_fields" filter. Please go through the official [documentation](https://woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/#overriding-core-fields). It will solve your issue.

Example:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'fs_rename_woo_checkout_fields' );
  
function fs_rename_woo_checkout_fields( $address_fields ) {
    $address_fields['address_1']['placeholder'] = 'House number, street name and block number';
    $address_fields['address_1']['label'] = 'Address';
    return $address_fields;
}
```